# What folders should I exclude / not exclude when migrating a server using rsync

Tags: rsync, django

I've got a requirement to migrate a web server onto a fresh server (both 32 bit and Fedora 15).  I'm using [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/migrating-a-linux-server-from-the-command-line-0) guide as I've very little experience with linux, coming from a windows background.

So essentially the existing web server runs apache, mysql and has web apps in php and python (using django CMS).  I've tried migrating once using the list of exclude files and directories suggested in the above article but this bricked the destination server so I had to rebuild the VM.

I'm now going to have a second go at it and I'm thinking I should try and exclude as many directories as possible.  I'd appreciate some help in deciding which directories I should add to the exclude and which I should allow in order to let it copy the appropriate files across to run the web apps correctly.

Comment: Is this just a move from a physical server to a VM? In that case you should just migrate the files and adjust `grub.cfg` and `/etc/fstab`

Comment: essentially yeh, surely though if I copy everything across then there'll be issues with filesystems etc?  Just like it mentions in that article

Comment: well that didn't work, again the system is bricked and I've had to revert, any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry no. I have done this multiple times (SuSE and Ubuntu) but never with Fedora.